# iOS8 Trailing Closures in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
let callActionHandler = { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void) in
        let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Service Unavailable", message: "Sorry, the call feature is not available yet. Please retry later", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
    };    

// Code Snippet 1
let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call" + "123-000-\(indexPath.row)", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default ) { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        println("check this out")
}

// Code Snippet 2
let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call" + "123-000-\(indexPath.row)", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in  
        println("Lets check this out")
})

// Code Snippet 3
let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call" + "123-000-\(indexPath.row)", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default , handler: callActionHandler)
```

- Here we have 3 Code Snippets, my doubts are:

  1. What is the difference between Code Snippet 1 and Code Snippet 2 ?
  2. Which out of Snippet 1 or Snippet 2 is a better representation and should be used ?
  3. What does Code Snippet 1 exactly mean? Is it some sort of property (completion) observing in swift?
  4. The way iOS8 wants us to write is shown in Snippet 1, i.e., when I press enter while Xcode autocompletes, it gets converted to Snippet 1. Should we use Code Snippet 1 or still prefer using Snippet 2/3 as they are easily understood?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked:

> 1. What is the difference between Code Snippet 1 and Code Snippet 2 ?

Code snippet 1 is is employing the "trailing closure" rendition of snippet 2. See *Trailing Closure* discussion in [The Swift Programming Language: Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_151), which says:

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing closure is a closure expression that is written outside of (and after) the parentheses of the function call it supports

So snippet 1 and snippet 2 are doing precisely the same thing.

> 2. Which out of Snippet 1 or Snippet 2 is a better representation and should be used ?

Generally one would prefer the trailing closure syntax of snippet 1 because it's more concise. But use whatever makes your code's intent both clear and concise.

> 3. What does Code Snippet 1 exactly mean? Is it some sort of property (completion) observing in swift?

No, it is exactly the same thing as snippet 2.

> 4. The way iOS8 wants us to write is shown in Snippet 1, i.e., when I press enter while Xcode autocompletes, it gets converted to Snippet 1. Should we use Code Snippet 1 or still prefer using Snippet 2/3 as they are easily understood?

Again, use whatever you prefer and is most clear and concise. Generally people avail themselves of the trailing closure syntax when possible.

---

Personally, in addition to trailing closure syntax, I might avail myself of inferred types of the parameter and dot syntax of the enum to simplify this further:

```
let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call 123-000-\(indexPath.row)", style: .default) { action in
    print("check this out")
}
```